# How to combine two points in a CGAL triangulization?

Tags: c++, cgal

I'm working on a CGAL triangulization and I need to remove two points and insert a third one, I'm trying to do this like this :

```
  Face_iterator fit = T.faces_begin();
  for ( ; fit !=T.faces_end(); ++fit) {
  for(i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
    j = i + 1;
    if(j == 3){j = 0;}
      sm1 = sm1/2 + T.triangle(fit)[j].x();
      sm2 = sm2/2 + T.triangle(fit)[j].y();
      Point cluster_result(sm1,sm2);
      T.insert(cluster_result);
      vh1 = fit->vertex(i);
      vh2 = fit->vertex(j);
      T.remove(vh1);
      T.remove(vh2);
    }
}
```

But after I do my first 'remove' I get segmentation fault trying to remove the second point.

My guess is that when I remove the first one I lose the pointer reference to the second one, but how can I overcome this problem ?

Comment: *"how can i overcome this problem ?"* - You'll have to find this out yourself. Or produce a [mcve]. As asked, we cannot help you. We don't even know, what `T` is. However, iterating over a container, while it is being modified is hardly ever a good idea.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for pointing out that iterating is a bad ideia, I agree.
I asked because most libraries like CGAL have a "combine" function, where you take two points and turn them into one with average X, Y and Z.

Comment: You got that wrong. Iterating isn't bad. Iterating over a sequence **while that sequence changes** is bad. Assuming that you are using a standard container (why do we still not know, what type `T` is?) like a `std::vector`, any call to `insert` and `remove` invalidates all iterators you previously constructed. Simple solution: Store your results in a new container.